# Links para arquivos pdf em pagina HTML usando o Android Studio asset diretório

Tags: android

Olá.
Tenho um página em HTML em um servidor com diversos links para arquivos pdf no windows e estou trazendo esta mesma página e o código junto com os pdfs para um App para Android. Estou usando o Android Studio e colocando os arquivos diretamente no diretório assets, incorporando-os ao App. Infelizmente os links agora não abrem os arquivos pdfs. Os links html foram modificados para o diretório novo do asset como: href = "file:///android_assest/nome_do_arq.pdf". É como não existisse o leitor de Pdf (Pdf view). Quando abro um arquivo index.html pelo App, no mesmo path do asset ou abro um arquivo pdf pelo meu "file explorer" incorporado ao App o arquivo abre normalmente. Somente não consigo abri-lo pelo link da página html como mostrado anteriormente. Agradeceria se aguem tivesse alguma dica pra abrir esse link já que eu gostaria de aproveitar a página já construida.  [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os href´s em azul são as chamadas dentro da página html. A chamada do teste.html abre normalmente mas os outro links pdfs não.

Quando tento abrir o arquivo PDF pelo link na pagina html ele não abre. Parece que o link não é interpretado apesar do arquivo de teste.pdf estar no mesmo diretório do arquivo teste.html. Estou usando o https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer linkado no meu aplicativo no meu app em Android 8.0

O arquivo html, exemplo básico, para fazer o link ao pdf file é o seguinte:
"o arquivo teste.html e o arquivo teste.pdf estão no mesmo diretório do App android (diretório android_asset).

href="teste.pdf"  "tb não abre pdf"

href="http://www.google.com"> Google   "abre google"

iframe src="teste.pdf"  /iframe  "tb não abre pdf"

Já tentei usar os formatos de links no href como p.exemplo:

"href="android_asset/teste.pdf"

"href="file:///android_asset/teste.pdf"

"href="file://android_asset/teste.pdf"

em JS também:
 "embed src="teste.pdf" type="application/pdf" witdh="100%" height="100%"

Aparece erro de "pagina não encontrada ou URL" ou então fica o fundo branco como se fosse renderizar o pdf e nada acontece.

Alguém tem alguma dica que possa informar porque isto pode estar acontecendo ?
Obrigado à todos

Answer (score -1):

Você pode visualizar ou baixar o PDF , por exemplo, abrindo-o no navegador incorporado do dispositivo ou na visualização da Web, incorporando-o ao seu aplicativo.

Abrir o pdf no browser,

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Abrir em um webview no app:

```
 Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(pdf_url);
```

Abrir num visualizador de PDF (Deve ter algum instalado no celular):

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

Intent pdfintent = new Intent();
pdfintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(yourfile);
pdfintent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
context.startActivity(pdfintent);
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Estou usando Kotlin. Já testei os exemplos. As permissões estão ativas. O acesso ao pdf através do html não funciona. Parece que a lib pdf view que compilei no aplicativo não renderiza os pdf files ou os arquivos não são achados no diretorio asset. Parece que os arquivos no diretório "assets" são combinados no "release" e a chamada do html externo não acha os files.Tentarei: <tags> em html5: <object data="teste.pdf#page=1" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
   <p><b>Examplo</b>: O browser não suporta PDFs. download para ve-lo: <a href="teste.pdf">Download</a>.</p>
</object>

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi o problema instalando um servidor web para android e usando o endereço localhost 127.0.0.1:8080 para minha página. usando o kotlin webview.loadUrl(href="127.0.0.1:8080/index.html") Os arquivos pdfs anexados a minha pagina web e foram abertos sem problemas. Os arquivos pdfs foram colocados com endereço relativo. Usei a mesma pasta do index.html.